# Destroying multiple references to the same object in Java

Tags: java, oop, reference, garbage-collection

Say I have a **Citizen** class and a **Population** class. A population contains a set of citizens.

In this simulation, citizens may die. Currently, to represent the death of a citizen, I destroy all references to that citizen object, as a Population may not contain a dead citizen.

I want to be able to create multiple Population objects where citizen overlap is possible. Ex. Citizen C may belong to both Population A and Population B. However, this makes citizen deaths difficult as I would have to remove citizen C from both A and B on the event of a death. Sometimes A and B aren't even in the same scope.

Also, each citizen must belong to at least one population.

Generally speaking, how would I organize my Population and Citizen class to ensure that a citizen is completely removed from all instances of Population upon that citizen's death?

I'm thinking of making Citizen a member class of Population, but I do not know where to go from there.

Thanks.

Comment: how about Citizen contains a list of populations she belongs to.

Comment: That is the most preferable solution right now, but I hesitate to store a list of Population references for each citizen, as my simulation may involve tens of thousands of citizens and hundreds of populations and that seems like a lot of wasted memory. If a better solution doesn't come along, I'll probably go with it though. Thanks.

Comment: In thats case, maybe do not store the entire Population Object in the list, but simply its `id` or other key in the list.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, but aren't lists of Objects stored by reference? I'm not sure how List<Integer> would save a significant amount of memory compared to List<Population>.

Comment: You are correct. Generally for object references, on a 32-bit machine it is 32 bits and on a 64-bit machine it is 64 bits.  So you may gain a little bit by using a primitive int.  But there again, it probably is not worth the effort and I would go for my original solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of it as a real life scenario, if a citizen belongs to few populations, then in case of death those populations need to be informed (lets say, if he is French and American, both countries need to know that to cancel his passport etc.). So the observer pattern here, as @nablex suggested, sounds like the most appropriate solution.
Have a class, like 'MinistryOfDeath' or something, that will inform the relevant populations.

Comment: Looked over all the answers and I'm going to choose this one. This is something I had not considered, as opposed to a isDead() solution ( nablex) and a back reference to each population (even if I used shorts).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this problem like observer pattern etc but if having a reverse link from citizen to population is already considered too heavy, any solution in that direction is probably too heavy weight.

If you **really** don't want a reverse link (though probably the best option and memory probably won't suffer *that* badly), you can always have an isDead() on the citizen.

Any population must then either periodically or upon access prune the dead citizens.

Answer (score 0):

When compared to `List<Population`, an `int[]` with numbering all the populations would save half the memory only on machines with above something like 32 GB, where compressed OOPs don't get suffice, otherwise nothing.

Using a `short[]` saves half the memory when compared to `int[]`. Using a `BitSet` saves much more.  You could even run your own, e.g., 2 `long`s for a fixed set of 128 populations and use only 16 bytes per `Citizen`. This is much much cheaper than the forward links from `Population`s to `Citizen`s.